# About the Magento 2 Multivendor Extension

Tags: magento2.2, extensions, marketplace, multi-vendor

I want to get the **profile of the vendor** who created the **product** on the product detail page.

I think it would be nice if I could get all **my profiles**.
Please let me know how I can get a profile.

Comment: did you use 3rd extension, I think magento2 does not have marketplace for default ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Multi Vendor Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/purpletree-marketplace.html) and one blog is here which provide some links [Magento 2 Multivendor Marketplace Extensions 2018](https://www.mageplaza.com/review/marketplace-extension/).